# Getting data from Parse in condition

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

Hey guys I have a lot of inputs about one content in Parse. I want to get number of inputs about one comment. Similar to counting likes. How can I do that?

```
let guessstat:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Guesscontent")
var guessData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
func loadData(){

    guessData.removeAllObjects()

    let findTimeLineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Guesses")

    findTimeLineData.whereKey("content", equalTo: self.guessTextView.text)
    findTimeLineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects{

                    self.guessData.addObject(object)

                }
            }
            let array:NSArray = self.guessData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.guessData = NSMutableArray(array: array)


        }

    }
    guessstat["sell"] = guessData.count

}
```

Comment: Are you just counting the "comments" and disregarding the comment itself? you can use PFquey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Comment: Might be time to start moving away from parse. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: @EncioPeter Yes,in a class I just want to count inputs that have same "content" which is equal to content in Tableviewcell. I know in my code I am using but may be I couldnt do properly "wherekey".

Comment: @GörkemKoşar what I understand from ur question that you want to count only no. of rows from query. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Each Input in your app corresponds to one Comment. Have you created a relationship between the actual guess and the guessing content?

First, it is possible you need to create a relationship between the two classes...

```
var Guesscontent = PFObject(className:"GuessContent")

var Guesses = PFObject(className:"Guesses")

//Create the relationship
Guesses["parent"] = GuessContent

//Everytime a user has made a guess, save it
Guesses.saveInBackground()
```

Then try what you are doing... let me know, I can't comment

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found solution

let query = PFQuery(className:"Guesses")

```
    query.whereKey("content", equalTo:self.guessTextView.text)
    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

    (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil

        {
        self.stattlabelsell.text = "\(count)"
        }
    }
```